# Route53 with SSL Cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I'm currently using AWS Route 53 for my domain (`domain.com`), I also generated an wildcard SSL cert from an external certificate authority (`*.subdomain.com`). I have installed the certificate in ACM.

My domain (domain.com) points to an ELB, which has 2 EC2 instances connected to it (`1.1.1.1` and `1.1.1.2`).

I want to create a subdomain (`sub.domain.com`) which points specifically to `1.1.1.2` and also has the SSL cert installed.

I've tried adding an A record in Route 53 with the subdomain pointing to the specific IP (`1.1.1.2`), this works, but when I add the `https` protocol it refuses to connect.

I pretty new with SSL and routing so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Route53 doesn't serve SSL certificates. Your load balancer is serving the SSL certificate. When you point a domain directly to an EC2 instance you have no way of attaching the ACM certificate to that domain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe AWS ACM does not support certificate for EC2. it only support for ELB, API Gateway and CloudFront. Please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

So you cannot connect with https on EC2 with certificate imported in AWS. You need to create own certificate manually on EC2.

Below note from AWS for ACM certificate on EC2

Public ACM certificates can be installed on Amazon EC2 instances that are connected to a Nitro Enclave, but not to other Amazon EC2 instances. For information about setting up a stand-alone web server on an Amazon EC2 instance not connected to a Nitro Enclave, see Tutorial: Install a LAMP web server on Amazon Linux 2 or Tutorial: Install a LAMP web server with the Amazon Linux AMI.